# Function behaving differently when being called from different form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using AJAX to make a call on my server, and the function is behaving differently depending on where I am calling it from. Here is a snippet of code that is in question:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    function showHint(str)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        alert("call made"); 
        if (str.length==0)
          { 
          document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
          return;
          }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","myAjax.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
<form action=""> 
First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint('hey')" /> 
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p> 

<tr><td><a href=/upload/actionscript.xml>actionscript.xml</a></td><td>0.03 MB</td><td>June 17 2014 11:29:29</td><td> <a href='' onclick="showHint('hey')" /> <img src="images/trash.png" alt="Delete" width="25" height="25"></a></td><tr>
</body>
</html>
```

So when I type something in the text field, everything works good and is it should, it gets thought both alerts.
When I click on the href, the only alert popping up is the "call made". What would be a reason for this

Comment: A.) Don't use alerts for trouble-shooting. They halt your JavaScript and might make your results unpredictable. 2.) Use `console.log()`.

Comment: Does your `<a>` link surrondded with `<img/>`?

Comment: Why should clicking on the `<a>` call the function at all?  There's no event handler assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the problem. Thank you Jay Blachard for telling me about console.log(), that helps a lot! 
The reason why I was not getting the response I was looking for was because I was making a reference to '', which seems it refreshes the page in the background or something. I have changed the code to :

```
<a href='#' onclick="showHint('hey')" /> 
     <img src="images/trash.png" alt="Delete" width="25" height="25">
</a>
```

And everything is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Remove the forward slash(/) in `<a /> .. </a>`

```
                                     <!--  Remove this slash   -->
<a href='' onclick="showHint('hey')" /> 
     <img src="images/trash.png" alt="Delete" width="25" height="25">
</a>
```